# Compare 2 nested JSON and highlight the differences them Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I am working on a requirement where I need to compare 2 JSON Objects. Comparing JSON 1 and JSON 2 should be such that the Result JSON should be JSON1 keys and the values should be fetched from JSON2. The values should only be changed for same keys with different values. Also, I need to highlight only the changed values in the result. Here is my code where I have been able to compare and get the JSON result, I am only stuck with highlighting the changed values. May I know where did I go wrong or what is missing?

```
  var compareJSON = function(obj1, obj2) { 
  var ret = {}; 
  for(var i in obj2) { 
    if(!obj1.hasOwnProperty(i) || obj2[i] !== obj1[i]) { 
      ret[i] = obj2[i]; 
    } 
  } 
  return ret; 
}; 

//JSON 1

var a = {
  "name": [
    "complex"
  ],
  "dfts": [
    {
      "valuec": {
        "valuesid": "1232"
      },
      "ids": {
        "idp": "chanellp"
      }
    }
  ],
  "container": {
    "contid": "na",
    "dpvalueus": {
      "ftsme": "na"
    },
    "attributes": {
      "channelpo": "na"
    },
    "item": [
      {
        "contid": {
          "stjsk": "wher"
        },
        "quantity": "na",
        "dpvalue": {
          "valuers": "na"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
  
};

//JSON 2

var b = {
  "name": [
    "simple"
  ],
  "dfts": [
    {
      "valuec": {
        "valuesid": "75756754"
      },
      "ids": {
        "idp": "where"
        
      }
    }
  ],
  "container": {
    "contid": "360",
    "dpvalueus": {
      "ftsme": "100"      
    },
    "attributes": {
      "channelpo": "usual"
    },
    "item": [
      {
        "contid": {
          "stjsk": "stkh"
        },
        "quantity": "1",
        "dpvalue": {
          "valuers": "wholesome"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
  
};

console.log(compareJSON(a, b));
```

Result can be seen in console.

Comment: How would you like to highlight the changed values?

Comment: @Moutah like a background in yellow color, using css

Comment: So, that is not JSON. When updating the values, you need to track which one is updated. That would be in another object or with another function.

Comment: @Moutah how can I do that? Any example?

Answer (score 0):

I would add the functionality that your are missing ( highlight the differences) here:

Change

```
if(!obj1.hasOwnProperty(i) || obj2[i] !== obj1[i]) { 
  ret[i] = obj2[i]; 
}
```

To:

```
  if(!obj1.hasOwnProperty(i)) { 
    ret[i] = obj2[i]; 
    continue;
  } 

  if( obj2[i] !== obj1[i] ) 
    {
     obj2[i]->diffent = true;
     ret[i] = obj2[i];
     continue;
    }


    ret[i] = obj2[i];
```

Comment: Thanks but It gives a syntax error (Unexpected token '>') here obj2[i]->diffent = true;

Comment: Right, change it to `obj2[i]['diffent'] = true`

Comment: Super. Please mark the answer as correct. It can be useful to somebody else :)

Comment: it is highlighting the complete object, I only want to highlight the changed value

Comment: What do you mean? Please explain further

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217029/discussion-between-ravi-shah-and-raffobaffo).

Comment: See I will be having 2 complex nested json with keys for both the json same, only the values would be different. Result: {JSON1 keys: JSON2 values}
But your code is highlighting the entire object and not the changed value